# how to filter and sum the aggs result in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

how to filter the aggs data in elasticsearch

i aggs the docs with my condition and successfully get the result.but i don't know how to filter the result doc count

this is my DSL

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "company": "ailsx"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "date_aggs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "date",
        "size": 30
      },
      "aggs": {
        "wang": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "customer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is my result

```
{
  "took": 1864,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 378426,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [

    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "date_aggs": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1553212800000,
          "key_as_string": "2019-03-22 00:00:00",
          "doc_count": 107879,
          "wang": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 10,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 107855,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "sfa",
                "doc_count": 4
              },
              {
                "key": "237692469",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "fasf",
                "doc_count": 3
              },
              {
                "key": "1111daaa",
                "doc_count": 2
              },
              {
                "key": "2011",
                "doc_count": 2
              }]}}]}}
```

i want to filter the doc_count which bigger than 2, and sum the count,like this

SELECT  Count(*) FROM doc
GROUP BY date, customer HAVING count(*)>=2

Comment: which version of elasticsearch are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `min_doc_count` for this purpose:

```
    "wang": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer",
        "min_doc_count": 2           <-- add this
      }
    }
```

Then the `doc_count` property of the bucket will be your sum.

Comment: how to apply below logic

var queryable1 = queryable.GroupBy(g => g.Date).Select(x => new GroupChartDto()
            {
                DailyPnL = x.Sum(s => s.DailyPnL),
                Date = x.Key,
                AggregateSum = queryable.Where(w => w.Date.Date <= x.Key.Date).Sum(s => s.DailyPnL)
            }).ToList();

Comment: @surendraKandira please create a new thread with your issue